JavaScript Web Animation, delay is ignored when trying to reverse?
I've created a stack of animations using JavaScript Web Animations, which gradually fade out characters in e.g. a sentence. I've achieved this by applying a staggered delay property to the keyframe timing object for the web animation.
I then try to reverse this animation stack, however the delay seems to be completely ignored in this case, and all the animations happen at the same time.
Is this a bug or expected behavior (i.e. I would need to write a dedicated animation stack to make the last characters to disappear also the first one to appear again)?


const animationContainer = document.querySelector("#animation-container");
const buttonStart = document.querySelector("#button-start");
const buttonReverse = document.querySelector("#button-reverse");
const buttonPlaybackRate = document.querySelector("#button-playbackRate");
const buttonUpdatePlaybackRate = document.querySelector("#button-updatePlaybackRate");

const animationDefinitionDefault = {
  keyframes: [
    { opacity: "1" },
    { opacity: "0.1" },
  ],

  timing: {
    duration: 500,
    delay: 0,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: "linear",
    fill: "both",
  }
};


// Create our animations
const animationStack = [];
const characters = animationContainer.querySelectorAll("span");

// Create the animation for each character
characters.forEach((character, index) => {
  const delay = index * 250; // Stagger the animations
  const animationDefinition = structuredClone(animationDefinitionDefault);

  animationDefinition.timing.delay = delay;

  animationStack[index] = character.animate(...Object.values(animationDefinition));
  animationStack[index].pause();
});


// Start button
buttonStart.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.playbackRate = 1;
    animation.play();
  });
});


// Reverse buttons
buttonReverse.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.reverse();
  });
});

buttonPlaybackRate.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.playbackRate = -1;
    animation.play();
  });
});

buttonUpdatePlaybackRate.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.updatePlaybackRate(-1);
    animation.ready.then(() => {
      animation.play();
    });
  });
});
#animation-container {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
}
<div id="animation-container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
</div>

<button type="button" id="button-start">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="button-reverse">reverse()</button>
<button type="button" id="button-playbackRate">playbackRate = -1</button>
<button type="button" id="button-updatePlaybackRate">updatePlaybackRate(-1)</button>




Answering my own question here.
I assume it's not possible at all with the way the animations are set up. The .reverse() functionality would only work if the it would be a single animation, or if you could somehow "queue" or group animations, so that they know they're depending on each other (Babylon.js seems to have something like this?).
So instead I had to set the delay property to 0 and modify the endDelay property, as apparently for playback in reverse, the endDelay takes over what delay does when being played forwards.
Here's some modified example code:


const animationContainer = document.querySelector("#animation-container");
const buttonStart = document.querySelector("#button-start");
const buttonReverse = document.querySelector("#button-reverse");

const animationDefinitionDefault = {
  keyframes: [
    { opacity: "1" },
    { opacity: "0.1" },
  ],

  timing: {
    duration: 500,
    delay: 0,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: "linear",
    fill: "both",
  }
};


// Create our animations
const animationStack = [];
const originalDelays = [];
const characters = animationContainer.querySelectorAll("span");


// Create the animation for each character
characters.forEach((character, index) => {
  const delay = index * 250; // Stagger the animations
  const animationDefinition = structuredClone(animationDefinitionDefault);

  // Store our original delay, so that it can be re-applied
  originalDelays.push(delay);
  animationDefinition.timing.delay = delay;

  animationStack[index] = character.animate(...Object.values(animationDefinition));
  animationStack[index].pause();
});


// Start button
buttonStart.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach((animation, index) => {
    // We need to reset any possible alterations done by the reverse call
    animation.effect.updateTiming({ delay: originalDelays[index], endDelay: 0 });
    animation.updatePlaybackRate(1);
    animation.ready.then(() => {
      animation.play();
    });
  });
});


// Reverse button
buttonReverse.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const reverseDelays = originalDelays.toReversed();

  for ( let i = animationStack.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    // We need to update our delay and endDelay
    // endDelay is used instead of delay for playback in reverse
    animationStack[i].effect.updateTiming({ delay: 0, endDelay: reverseDelays[i] });
    animationStack[i].reverse();
  }
});
#animation-container {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
}
  <div id="animation-container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" id="button-start">Start</button>
  <button type="button" id="button-reverse">reverse()</button>




You might do it changing the direction property.


const animationContainer = document.querySelector("#animation-container");
const buttonStart = document.querySelector("#button-start");
const buttonReverse = document.querySelector("#button-reverse");
const buttonPlaybackRate = document.querySelector("#button-playbackRate");
const buttonUpdatePlaybackRate = document.querySelector("#button-updatePlaybackRate");

const animationDefinitionDefault = {
  keyframes: [
    {opacity: "1"},
    {opacity: "0.1"},
  ],

  timing: {
    duration: 500,
    delay: 0,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: "linear",
    fill: "both",
  }
};


// Create our animations
const animationStack = [];
const characters = animationContainer.querySelectorAll("span");

// Create the animation for each character
characters.forEach((character, index) => {
  const delay = index * 250; // Stagger the animations
  const animationDefinition = structuredClone(animationDefinitionDefault);

  animationDefinition.timing.delay = delay;

  animationStack[index] = character.animate(...Object.values(animationDefinition));
  animationStack[index].pause();
});


// Start button
buttonStart.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.playbackRate = 1;
    animation.effect.updateTiming({
      direction: 'normal'
    });
    animation.play();
  });
});


// Reverse buttons
buttonReverse.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.effect.updateTiming({
      direction: 'reverse'
    });
    animation.play();
  });
});

buttonPlaybackRate.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.playbackRate = -1;
    animation.play();
  });
});

buttonUpdatePlaybackRate.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  animationStack.forEach(animation => {
    animation.updatePlaybackRate(-1);
    animation.ready.then(() => {
      animation.play();
    });
  });
});
#animation-container {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
}
<div id="animation-container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
</div>

<button type="button" id="button-start">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="button-reverse">reverse()</button>
<button type="button" id="button-playbackRate">playbackRate = -1</button>
<button type="button" id="button-updatePlaybackRate">updatePlaybackRate(-1)</button>




Something, but not quite. It should start at 6 and then go back to 1. But thinking further about this, the .reverse() functionality would probably only work if this was a single animation, or something like a "true" animation queue/group, because the individual animations don't know about each other. I guess I'll have to write the reverse functionality myself.
It's still odd though that the delay isn't considered at all, unlike in your solution.

@sp00n, sorry for misunderstanding your question. You're right, you have to reverse the delays as well. BTW the whole thing might be done simpler and easier using CSS animations instead of WAAPI.

Reversing the delays itself didn't work, I actually had to use the endDelay property instead. See the answer I provided with updated code.
